# Units of measure regex manipulation

Tags: regex, perl, awk

### Objective

On **[Linux](http://www.linux.org/)**, I am trying to get an *end-user friendly* string representing available system memory.

Example:

```
Your computer has 4 GB of memory.
```

---

#### Success criteria

I consider these aspects *end-user friendly* (you may disagree):

- `1G` is more readable than `1.0G` (`1` Vs `1.0`)
- `1GB` is more readable than `1G` (`GB` Vs `G`)
- `1 GB` is more readable than `1GB` (`space-separated` unit of measure)
- `memory` is more readable than `RAM`, `DDR` or `DDR3` (no jargon)

#### Starting point

The **[free](http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/blobs/master/free.c)** utility from **[procps-ng](http://gitorious.org/procps)** has an option intended for humans:

```
-h, --human
    Show all output fields automatically scaled to shortest three digit unit
    and display the units of print out.  Following units are used.
        B = bytes
        K = kilos
        M = megas
        G = gigas
        T = teras
    If unit is missing, and you have petabyte of RAM or swap, the number is
    in terabytes and columns might not be aligned with header.
```

so I decided to start there:

```sh
> free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3.8G       1.4G       2.4G         0B       159M       841M
-/+ buffers/cache:       472M       3.4G
Swap:         4.9G         0B       3.9G
```

`3.8G` sounds promising so all I have to do now is...

#### Required steps

- Filter the output for the line containing the human-readable string (i.e. `Mem:`)
- Pick out the memory total from the middle of the line (i.e. `3.8G`)
- Parse out the number and unit of measure (i.e. `3.8` and `G`)
- Format and display a string more to my liking (e.g. `G`↝ `GB`, ...)

#### My attempt

```sh
free -h | \
  awk  '/^Mem:/{print $2}' | \
    perl -ne '/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(B|K|M|G|T)/ && printf "%g %sB\n", $1, $2'
```

outputs:

```
3.8 GB
```

---

#### Desired solution

- I'd prefer to just use **[gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)**, but I don't know how
- Use a better, even *canonical* if there is one, way to parse a "float" out of a string
- I don't mind the *fastidious* matching of "just the recognised magnitude letters" `(B|K|M|G|T)`, even if this would unnecessarily break the match with the introduction of new sizes
- I use `%g` to output `4.0` as `4`, which is something you may disagree with, depending on how you feel about these comments: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70553/10283.

### My question, in summary

- Could you do the above in `awk` only?
- Could my `perl` be written more elegantly than that, keeping the strictness of it?

Remember:

```
I am a beginner robot. Here to learn. :]
```

---

#### What I learned from Andy Lester

*Summarised here for my own benefit: to cement learning, if I can.*

- Use **[regex character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**, not **[regex alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)**, to pick out one character from a set
- **[perl](http://www.perl.org/)** has a `-a` option, which splits `$_` from `-e` or `-n` into `@F`:

for example, this **[gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)**:

```sh
echo foo bar baz | awk '{print $2}'
```

can be written like this in **[perl](http://www.perl.org/)**:

```sh
echo foo bar baz | perl -ane 'print "$F[1]\n";'
```

*Unless there is something equivalent to* **[gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)** *'s `--field-separator`, I think I still like* **[gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)** *better, although of course to do everything in* **[perl](http://www.perl.org/)** *is both cleaner and more efficient.* (is there an equivalent?)

---

**EDIT**: actually, this proves there is, and it's `-F` just like in **[gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)**:

```
echo ooxoooxoooo | perl -Fx -ane 'print join "\n", @F'
```

outputs:

```
oo
ooo
oooo
```

---

- **[perl](http://www.perl.org/)** has a `-l` option, which is just awesome: think of it as **[Python](http://python.org/)**'s **[str.rstrip](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip)** (see the link if you are not a **[Python](http://python.org/)** head) for the validity of `$_` but it re-appends the `\n` to the output automatically for you

*Thanks, Andy!*

---

Comment: I say +1 for having an organized question.  But you may get better feedback on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks. I was _very hesitant_ to post a "shell one-liner" to a site called _Code Review_! It felt borderline obsessive.. :)

Comment: I agree with Stephane. There is no reason for precision to change just because the output happen to fall on an even number.

Comment: Computer science point of view. Logical, precise. I think my "grandma" would still say `4 GB` to a shop attendant rather than `4.0G`. At any rate, the question regarding regex remains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *awk* (actually *gawk*) solution

```
free -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {if (match($2,"[BKMGT]$",a)) r=sprintf("%.0f %sB",substr($2,0,RSTART-1), a[0]); else r=$2 " B";print "Your computer has " r " of memory."}'
```

or broken down for readability

```
free -h | awk 'FNR == 2 {if (match($2,"[BKMGT]$",a)) r=sprintf("%.0f %sB",
          substr($2,0,RSTART-1), a[0]); else r=$2 " B";
          print "Your computer has " r " of memory."}'
```

Where

- `FNR` is the n<sup>th</sup> line (if `2` does the `{}` commands)
- `$2` is the 2<sup>nd</sup> field
- `if` (condition) command; `else` command;
- `match`(string, regex, matches array). Regex says "must end with one of BKMGT"
- `r=sprintf` set variable `r` to *sprintf* with `%.0f` for no decimals float
- `RSTART` tells where the match occured, `a[0]` is the first match

Outputs with the exemple above

```
Your computer has 4 GB of memory.
```

Comment: Awarding, as it is `awk` all the way. Andy's solution looks cleaner to me, I would probably remember that more easily, but since it's all `awk`, the "prize" is yours! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm sure you could do this awk-only, but I'm a Perl guy so here's how you'd do it Perl-only.

Instead of `(B|K|M|G|T)` use `[BKMGT]`.

Use Perl's `-l` to automatically strip newlines from input and add them on output.

I don't see any reason to have Awk do some of the stripping and Perl doing the rest.  You can do autosplitting of fields with Perl's -a.

I don't know what the output from `free -h` is exactly (My `free` doesn't have an `-h` option) so I'm guessing at this

```
free -h | \
perl -alne'/^Mem:/ && ($F[1]=~/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[BKMGT]/) && printf( "%g %sB", $1, $2)'
```

Comment: Whoa.. I **LOVE** this answer! Damn! You taught me so much in a one-liner! Awesome!! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it.  Go ahead and accept it, please.  This presentation I gave years ago may give you some more tidbits.  https://speakerdeck.com/petdance/a-field-guide-to-the-perl-command-line

Comment: I absolutely adore your answer, but I am going to wait just a little bit for an `awk` one, in case it comes. It was my expressed preference. Good to learn some perl from a Master like you though. Will accept in case no awk comes forward..

Comment: BTW, Andy, I have noticed the `-l` switch does not "work" in this one-liner.. `free -h | perl -lane '/^Mem:/ && ($F[1] =~ /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([BKMGT])/) && printf "%g %sB", $1, $2'`

Comment: Should `-l` not add a `\n`? It does not in that one-liner.. so I called this: "does not work". Am I wrong? (notice how I thank you for your answer in my addendum to the Q above) I think this is because we use `printf` rather than plain-ol' `print`?

Comment: Interesting.  The `-l` will add `\n` after a `print` but not after a `printf`.  From the manual `perldoc -f print`: "Equivalent to `print FILEHANDLE sprintf(FORMAT, LIST)`, except that `$\` (the output record separator) is not appended."

Answer (score 0):

Another lengthy Perl answer:

```
free -b | 
perl -lane 'if(/Mem/){ @u=("B","KB","MB","GB"); $F[2]/=1024, shift @u while ($F[2]>1024); printf("%.2f %s", $F[2],$u[0])}'
```